# Implicit Differentiation: $(x/y)+(y/x) =1$

Tags: implicit-differentiation

Hi can anyone please tell me where I goes wrong with this question:

Find $ \frac{dy}{dx} $ for the curves defines by this equation:

\begin{align}
   \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} = 1 
 \end{align}

Here is what I did:

\begin{align}
    &\frac{y-xy'}{y^2} + \frac{y'x - y}{x^2} =0 \\
    &\frac{yx^2 - x^3 y'+y'y^2 x - y^3}{x^2 y^2} = 0 \\
    &yx^2 + (-x^3 +y^2 x)y' -y^3 =0 \\
    &\therefore y'= \frac{y^3 -yx^2}{-x^3 +y^2x}
\end{align}

The answer say it should be: $ y' = \frac{y}{x} $ but I had no clue how to proceed from there.

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! Nice work explaining and typesetting your work. As to your question: You can cancel $y^2-x^2$ in your expression and then you are there.

Comment: Oh wow I can't believe I didn't see it when I post the question! Thanks very much! Hans

Comment: If we write $u := \frac{x}{y}$, then the l.h.s. is $u + \frac{1}{u}$, but this does not take values in $(-2, 2)$ for real $u$, so the given relation is empty and there's nothing to compute.

Comment: @Travis did you mean the equation is not a relation and thus should Not have a $ \frac{dy}{dx}$ ?

Comment: The equation defines a relation, but there are no $(x, y)$ that satisfy it, so the relation is empty, and hence there are no points at which to compute a derivative.

Comment: @Travis now that's quite interesting, if no (x, y) satisfies the relation then what does the supposed "solution" $ y' = \frac{y}{x} $ represent? (if not derivative)

Comment: At least it is the correct formula when we replace the r.h.s. of the defining equation with a value the l.h.s. does achieve.

Comment: @Travis I think this question is not intended to be interpreted geometrically.

Comment: @JustinHT So how should it be interpreted? That $x, y$ can be complex numbers?

Comment: @JustinHT The issue is not geometric, it's set-theoretic.

Comment: @LeonAragones I'm not sure too, this question confused me a lot.

Comment: @Travis sorry I'm not familiar to with set theory.

Comment: @JustinHT It's quite possible the question's author didn't foresee this complication. Probably it's best just to treat it as though the quantity on the r.h.s. is, e.g., $2$, in which case the arguments in the answers still apply (and are not vacuous).

Comment: @Travis yes I would agree. I think the author just intended it to be a practice question in implicit differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you going to do implicit differentiation you might as well multiply by $xy$ to get $x^2 + y^2 = xy$ before differencing. now differencing gives you $2xdx + 2ydy = xdy + ydx.$ this can also be written as 
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{y - 2x}{2y-x} = \dfrac{y(y-2x)}{y(2y-x)}=
\dfrac{y(y-2x)}{2y^2 - xy} = \dfrac{y(y-2x)}{2xy - 2x^2 - xy} = \dfrac{y(y-2x)}{x(y-2x)} = \dfrac{y}{x} \tag 1$$

in implicit differentiation you don't have a unique answer. you always have to carry the constraint $\dfrac{x}{y} + \dfrac{y}{x} = 1$ along or an equivalent one like $x^2 + y^2 = xy$ along with the solution. in the equality (1) any one of them could be an answer.

Comment: Hi abel can you explain how did you do this transformation: $$ \dfrac{y(y-2x)}{2y^2 - xy} = \dfrac{y(y-2x)}{2xy - 2x^2 - xy} $$ ?

Comment: @JustinHT, because i wanted an $y$ in the numerator and then the denominator better has a factor $y- 2x$ if we are going to match answer in the book.

Comment: I meant how not why.

Comment: @JustinHT,  i don't understand what you mean. we have $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y-2x}{2y - x}$ i just multiplied the numerator and denominator of the right hand side by $y.$

Comment: yes that would turn $$ \dfrac{y - 2x}{2y-x}$$ to $$\dfrac{y(y-2x)}{y(2y-x)} $$ but how did you turn this 
$$\dfrac{y(y-2x)}{2y^2 - xy} $$ to $$\dfrac{y(y-2x)}{2xy - 2x^2 - xy}$$

Comment: @JustinHT, because i used $y^2= xy - x^2$

Comment: oh I got it now Thanks! @abel

Answer (score 1):

**Note that $y=y(x)$**

So we have that 
$$\frac{x}{y(x)} + \frac{y(x)}{x} = 1$$

So,

$$\begin{align} 0 &= \frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{x}{y(x)} + \frac{y(x)}{x}\right) \\
&=\frac{d}{dx}(x) \frac{1}{y(x)}+x \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{y(x)}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{y(x)}+ x \ \frac{-1}{y^2(x)} \frac{dy}{dx} \\
&= \frac{1}{y(x)}\left(1-\frac{x}{y(x)} \right)\frac{dy}{dx}  
\end{align}$$

Assuming $\frac{1}{y(x)} \neq 0$ then

$$0= \left(1-\frac{x}{y(x)} \right)\frac{dy}{dx}   $$

$$-1= -\frac{x}{y(x)} \frac{dy}{dx} $$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y(x)}{x}=\frac{y}{x} $$

The only thing I used is the product rule http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule

Answer (score 0):

we get by the quotient and the chaine rule
$$\frac{y-xy'}{y^2}+\frac{y'x-y}{x^2}=0$$ multiplying by $x^2y^2$ we obtain
$$x^2y-x^3y'+y'y^2x-y^3=0$$
solving for $y'$ we get
$$y'=\frac{x^2y-y^3}{x^3-xy^2}$$ if $x^3-y^2x\ne 0$

Comment: Thanks Dr. Graubner. I'd already got it with the help of a commentor above.